# Tiny C Compiler link my assembly object file

Tags: c, assembly, linker, nasm, tcc

Is it possible to link a *.o file generated with nasm in tcc?

With gcc it works fine for me:

```
nasm -f win32 -o fastmath.o fastmath.asm
gcc -o powerTest.exe powerTest.cpp cexport.o
```

When I try the same procedure with tcc, i got the following error: fastmath.o:1: error: unrecognized file

```
set name=test
set tccpath=C:\TCC\
set nasmpath=C:\NASM\

%nasmpath%nasm -f win32 -o fastmath.o fastmath.asm

%tccpath%tcc -c main.c
%tccpath%tcc -vv -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -o %name%.exe main.o fastmath.o
```

Did i forget something in the compiling options?

Comment: maybe tcc's output file's format is not the same as the rest. Did you try linking an *.o file generated by tcc with a program in gcc?

Comment: Off topic, I strongly suggest you use latest from http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git , and make sure you use mob branch. tcc has very rare releases (once per few years sometimes), so the only way to benefit from updates is to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Tcc does not handle -f win32. Use -f coff instead.

Comment: @user3052010 Can you try with "-f elf".